# How to join multiple with one query on SQLIte3

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

Here are my case:

1. Table A: ID integer, Kind integer,

> (Kind=1 search Table B, Kind=2, search Table C)

2. Table B: ID, name, price
3. Table C: ID, item, amount

Table A

- ID | Kind
- 1  |  1
- 2  |  1
- 2  |  2
- 3  |  2

TABLE B

- ID    name     price
- 1     name1   2.0
- 2     name2   1.0

TABLE C

- ID    Item     amount
- 2     item2    1.0
- 3     item3    1.0

what I am trying to search with one query and the result like:

> `- ID  |  Kind |    name  |  price |  item. |   amount
>    - 1   |  1    |    name1 |  2.0   |  ----  |   -----
>    - 2   |  1    |    name2 |  1.0   |  ----  |.  -----
>    - 2   |  2    |    ----  |   ---  |  item2 |   1.0
>    - 3   |  2    |    ----  |   ---  |  item3 |   1.0`

Is it possible?

```
select A.ID,A.kind,B.name,B.price,C.item,C.amount from TableA 
case when Kind=1 Left Join TableB on A.ID=B.ID Then Left Join TableC on A.ID=C.ID order by ID
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected output.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to add  what I am trying to do

Comment: Why does the third row not have a name?  Both `ID` and `Kind` have a value of `2` there, so I would have expected a name.

Comment: third row name and price would be NULL, since combing ID and Kind point the to Table C. actually, what I am trying to do is to left join B, and then left join C with table A, table A has the combination from table B and table C.

Answer (score 1):

Just join with both tables, and make the `Kind` value part of the join condition. Use [outer joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join) to get TableA rows even when no match is found for one join:

```
SELECT TableA.ID,
       TableA.Kind,
       TableB.name,
       TableB.price,
       TableC.item,
       TableC.amount
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Kind = 1 AND TableA.ID = TableB.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.Kind = 2 AND TableA.ID = TableC.ID;
```

Alternatively, use normal joins in two separate queries, and [combine](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) them with lots of NULL columns:

```
SELECT TableA.ID,
       TableA.Kind,
       TableB.name,
       TableB.price,
       NULL AS item,
       NULL AS amout
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB USING (ID)
WHERE Table.Kind = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT TableA.ID,
       TableA.Kind,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       TableC.item,
       TableC.amount
FROM TableA
JOIN TableC USING (ID)
WHERE Table.Kind = 2;
```

Comment: greate Answer, Thanks CL,